# Install and enable the intl extension (used for validators). - MAC (Prestashop)

Tags: macos, xampp, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I´m trying to install Prestashop in Xampp but appears that error. i tryed to uncomment the line in php.ini of
"extension=php_intl.dll"
And then restart Xampp but the error is appearing.

I´m using php 7.2 and the version of Prestashop is 1.7.6.

Any idea?
[image]

Comment: What result do you get when you do php -m | grep intl in your terminal?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

After try a lot of differents solutions i installed again Mamp and now its works.

Answer (score 0):

It is saying it could not load the intl extension. Make sure your server loads the intl extension.

**WRONG:**

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

**CORRECT**

```
extension=php_intl.dll
```

The semicolon (;) needs to be removed. Restart your server and it should load your intl extension correctly.